# Positive definiteness of a matrix-valued function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, stochastic-processes, matrix-analysis, gaussian

*This question is a repost from [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4660807/1132955), where I didn't receive an answer.*

---

Are there simple conditions on an $d \times d$  matrix B under which
$$ 
f(t, s) 
= 
\begin{cases}
\exp(-B |t - s|^\alpha), & t > s, \\[7pt]
\exp(-B^\top |t - s|^\alpha), & t < s
\end{cases}
$$
with $\alpha \in (0,2)$ and $t, \, s \in \Bbb R$
is positive definite as a matrix-valued function *(see def below)*?

I know that it's true if $B$ is nonnegative definite (hence symmetric). But can these conditions be relaxed? Is it possible to show this for $B$ satisfying $B + B^\top \geq 0$ (eigenvalues have nonnegative real parts) without $B$ being symmetric (in particular, $B$ needs not be diagonalizable)?

---

**Example.** Consider a standard normal vector $\mathbf{N}$ and an antisymmetric matrix $V$. Define a Gaussian process $\mathbf{X} (t) = \exp(t V) \, \mathbf{N}$. Then
$$
\mathbb{E} \mathbf{X} (t) \, \mathbf{X}^\top (s) = \exp(V (t — s))
= \begin{cases}
\exp(V |t — s|), & t > s, \\[7pt]
\exp(V^\top |t — s|), & t < s
\end{cases}
$$
hence it is positive definite.

---

Is it true in general that if $r(t, s)$ is a positive definite **matrix-valued** function, then so is $\exp(r(t, s))$? This is obviously true if $r$ is scalar valued.

---

The reason for this particular question is that I am interested in the corresponding class of multivariate fractional Ornstein-Uhlenbeck processes.

---

P.S. By positive definiteness I mean
$$
\sum_{i, j} \mathbf{x}_i^\top f (t_i, t_j) \, \mathbf{x}_j \geq 0
\qquad \forall \, t_i \in \mathbb{R}, \quad \mathbf{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^d.
$$

Answer (score 0):

First a remark: the usual and widely used definition for positive definiteness is what you wrote at the very end of your question $\underline{\rm and}$ the fact that the matrix $F(t)=(f(t_i,t_j)_{1\le i, j\le  n}$ is non-singular. In other words, a matrix $F=(f_{i,j})_{1\le i, j\le  n}$ is positive definite if
$$
\forall x\in \mathbb R^n, \quad x\not=0\Longrightarrow\langle F x, x\rangle>0.
\tag{1}$$
Take now a $n\times n$ real-valued matrix satisfying (1); defining
$$
F_0=\frac12(F+F^T)\ \text{(a symmetric matrix)}, \quad F_1=\frac12(F-F^T)
\ \text{(a skew-symmetric matrix)}.
$$
Condition (1) means only that $F_0$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix and your question is in fact the following: let $A$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix, is it true that for any real-valued skew-symmetric matrix $S$, we have
$
e^{A+S}
$
is positive definite?

The answer is negative: take for instance
$$
A=I_2=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}, \quad 
S=π\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Since the matrices $A,S$ are commuting, we have
$$
e^{A+S}=e^Ae^S=\begin{pmatrix}e&0\\0&e\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\cosπ&-\sin π\\\sin π&\cos π\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}-e&0\\0&-e\end{pmatrix},
$$
which is a negative-definite matrix.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean... Thanks for helping me formulate the question more clearly.

Comment: Also thanks for the counterexample, it is nice and useful

Comment: I don't see why this is true: "your question is in fact the following: let $A$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix, is it true that for any real-valued skew-symmetric matrix $S$, we have 
$
e^{A+S}
$
is positive definite?"

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis The last question (about $r(t,s)$) is asking about $\exp r$ being positive-definite when $r$ is positive definite. Since $r$ can be written as the sum of a symmetric matrix and a skew-symmetric matrix, and moreover since the positiveness assumption does not concern the skew-symmetric part, you arrive at the question formulated in my answer ($A,S$ business).

Comment: @Bazin, positive definiteness of $r(t, s)$ as a matrix-valued function includes symmetricity of in the sense that $r^\top(t,s) = r(s, t)$. Consider the example I added. Although admittedly I seriously doubt that $\exp(r(t,s))$ is positive definite, but for different reasons to what you've suggested. It doesn't even seem possible (at least to me) to show that the square $r^2(t, s)$ is positive definite.

Comment: P.S. I know that Hadamard's (componentwise) exponential remains positive definite if $r$ is, but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @Bazin : I seems to me that in your response to my comment you just repeated, only less formally this time, the argument in your answer -- which I did not understand, as I do not understand it now.